# Only green display but temperature it's not showed there

Tags: atmega, lcd, lm35

I'm trying to build a graphic display thermometer in Proteus, with an LM35 sensor using the ATmega 164 microcontroller.

My problem is that the program that I've built it's only starting the display(it makes it green), but it's not displaying the temperature at all..I'm using the CodeVisionAVR IDE.

- What am I doing wrong?
- Are the wires connected OK? If not, why?
  [image]

```
      #include <mega164a.h>

#include <delay.h>

// Alphanumeric LCD functions
#include <alcd.h>

// Declare your global variables here

// Voltage Reference: 1.1V, cap. on AREF
#define ADC_VREF_TYPE ((1<<REFS1) | (0<<REFS0) | (1<<ADLAR))

// Read the 8 most significant bits
// of the AD conversion result
unsigned char read_adc(unsigned char adc_input)
{
ADMUX=adc_input | ADC_VREF_TYPE;
// Delay needed for the stabilization of the ADC input voltage
delay_us(10);
// Start the AD conversion
ADCSRA|=(1<<ADSC);
// Wait for the AD conversion to complete
while ((ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF))==0);
ADCSRA|=(1<<ADIF);
return ADCH;
}

void main(void)
{
// Declare your local variables here

// Crystal Oscillator division factor: 1
#pragma optsize-
CLKPR=(1<<CLKPCE);
CLKPR=(0<<CLKPCE) | (0<<CLKPS3) | (0<<CLKPS2) | (0<<CLKPS1) | (0<<CLKPS0);
#ifdef _OPTIMIZE_SIZE_
#pragma optsize+
#endif

// Input/Output Ports initialization
// Port A initialization
// Function: Bit7=In Bit6=In Bit5=In Bit4=In Bit3=In Bit2=In Bit1=In Bit0=In 
DDRA=(0<<DDA7) | (0<<DDA6) | (0<<DDA5) | (0<<DDA4) | (0<<DDA3) | (0<<DDA2) | (0<<DDA1) | (0<<DDA0);
// State: Bit7=T Bit6=T Bit5=T Bit4=T Bit3=T Bit2=T Bit1=T Bit0=T 
PORTA=(0<<PORTA7) | (0<<PORTA6) | (0<<PORTA5) | (0<<PORTA4) | (0<<PORTA3) | (0<<PORTA2) | (0<<PORTA1) | (0<<PORTA0);

// Port B initialization
// Function: Bit7=In Bit6=In Bit5=In Bit4=In Bit3=In Bit2=In Bit1=In Bit0=In 
DDRB=(0<<DDB7) | (0<<DDB6) | (0<<DDB5) | (0<<DDB4) | (0<<DDB3) | (0<<DDB2) | (0<<DDB1) | (0<<DDB0);
// State: Bit7=T Bit6=T Bit5=T Bit4=T Bit3=T Bit2=T Bit1=T Bit0=T 
PORTB=(0<<PORTB7) | (0<<PORTB6) | (0<<PORTB5) | (0<<PORTB4) | (0<<PORTB3) | (0<<PORTB2) | (0<<PORTB1) | (0<<PORTB0);

// Port C initialization
// Function: Bit7=In Bit6=In Bit5=In Bit4=In Bit3=In Bit2=In Bit1=In Bit0=In 
DDRC=(0<<DDC7) | (0<<DDC6) | (0<<DDC5) | (0<<DDC4) | (0<<DDC3) | (0<<DDC2) | (0<<DDC1) | (0<<DDC0);
// State: Bit7=T Bit6=T Bit5=T Bit4=T Bit3=T Bit2=T Bit1=T Bit0=T 
PORTC=(0<<PORTC7) | (0<<PORTC6) | (0<<PORTC5) | (0<<PORTC4) | (0<<PORTC3) | (0<<PORTC2) | (0<<PORTC1) | (0<<PORTC0);

// Port D initialization
// Function: Bit7=In Bit6=In Bit5=In Bit4=In Bit3=In Bit2=In Bit1=In Bit0=In 
DDRD=(0<<DDD7) | (0<<DDD6) | (0<<DDD5) | (0<<DDD4) | (0<<DDD3) | (0<<DDD2) | (0<<DDD1) | (0<<DDD0);
// State: Bit7=T Bit6=T Bit5=T Bit4=T Bit3=T Bit2=T Bit1=T Bit0=T 
PORTD=(0<<PORTD7) | (0<<PORTD6) | (0<<PORTD5) | (0<<PORTD4) | (0<<PORTD3) | (0<<PORTD2) | (0<<PORTD1) | (0<<PORTD0);

// Timer/Counter 0 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer 0 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFF
// OC0A output: Disconnected
// OC0B output: Disconnected
TCCR0A=(0<<COM0A1) | (0<<COM0A0) | (0<<COM0B1) | (0<<COM0B0) | (0<<WGM01) | (0<<WGM00);
TCCR0B=(0<<WGM02) | (0<<CS02) | (0<<CS01) | (0<<CS00);
TCNT0=0x00;
OCR0A=0x00;
OCR0B=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 1 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer1 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFFFF
// OC1A output: Disconnected
// OC1B output: Disconnected
// Noise Canceler: Off
// Input Capture on Falling Edge
// Timer1 Overflow Interrupt: Off
// Input Capture Interrupt: Off
// Compare A Match Interrupt: Off
// Compare B Match Interrupt: Off
TCCR1A=(0<<COM1A1) | (0<<COM1A0) | (0<<COM1B1) | (0<<COM1B0) | (0<<WGM11) | (0<<WGM10);
TCCR1B=(0<<ICNC1) | (0<<ICES1) | (0<<WGM13) | (0<<WGM12) | (0<<CS12) | (0<<CS11) | (0<<CS10);
TCNT1H=0x00;
TCNT1L=0x00;
ICR1H=0x00;
ICR1L=0x00;
OCR1AH=0x00;
OCR1AL=0x00;
OCR1BH=0x00;
OCR1BL=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 2 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer2 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFF
// OC2A output: Disconnected
// OC2B output: Disconnected
ASSR=(0<<EXCLK) | (0<<AS2);
TCCR2A=(0<<COM2A1) | (0<<COM2A0) | (0<<COM2B1) | (0<<COM2B0) | (0<<WGM21) | (0<<WGM20);
TCCR2B=(0<<WGM22) | (0<<CS22) | (0<<CS21) | (0<<CS20);
TCNT2=0x00;
OCR2A=0x00;
OCR2B=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 0 Interrupt(s) initialization
TIMSK0=(0<<OCIE0B) | (0<<OCIE0A) | (0<<TOIE0);

// Timer/Counter 1 Interrupt(s) initialization
TIMSK1=(0<<ICIE1) | (0<<OCIE1B) | (0<<OCIE1A) | (0<<TOIE1);

// Timer/Counter 2 Interrupt(s) initialization
TIMSK2=(0<<OCIE2B) | (0<<OCIE2A) | (0<<TOIE2);

// External Interrupt(s) initialization
// INT0: Off
// INT1: Off
// INT2: Off
// Interrupt on any change on pins PCINT0-7: Off
// Interrupt on any change on pins PCINT8-15: Off
// Interrupt on any change on pins PCINT16-23: Off
// Interrupt on any change on pins PCINT24-31: Off
EICRA=(0<<ISC21) | (0<<ISC20) | (0<<ISC11) | (0<<ISC10) | (0<<ISC01) | (0<<ISC00);
EIMSK=(0<<INT2) | (0<<INT1) | (0<<INT0);
PCICR=(0<<PCIE3) | (0<<PCIE2) | (0<<PCIE1) | (0<<PCIE0);

// USART0 initialization
// USART0 disabled
UCSR0B=(0<<RXCIE0) | (0<<TXCIE0) | (0<<UDRIE0) | (0<<RXEN0) | (0<<TXEN0) | (0<<UCSZ02) | (0<<RXB80) | (0<<TXB80);

// USART1 initialization
// USART1 disabled
UCSR1B=(0<<RXCIE1) | (0<<TXCIE1) | (0<<UDRIE1) | (0<<RXEN1) | (0<<TXEN1) | (0<<UCSZ12) | (0<<RXB81) | (0<<TXB81);

// Analog Comparator initialization
// Analog Comparator: Off
// The Analog Comparator's positive input is
// connected to the AIN0 pin
// The Analog Comparator's negative input is
// connected to the AIN1 pin
ACSR=(1<<ACD) | (0<<ACBG) | (0<<ACO) | (0<<ACI) | (0<<ACIE) | (0<<ACIC) | (0<<ACIS1) | (0<<ACIS0);
// Digital input buffer on AIN0: On
// Digital input buffer on AIN1: On
DIDR1=(0<<AIN0D) | (0<<AIN1D);

// ADC initialization
// ADC Clock frequency: 625.000 kHz
// ADC Voltage Reference: 1.1V, cap. on AREF
// ADC Auto Trigger Source: Free Running
// Only the 8 most significant bits of
// the AD conversion result are used
// Digital input buffers on ADC0: On, ADC1: On, ADC2: On, ADC3: On
// ADC4: On, ADC5: On, ADC6: On, ADC7: On
DIDR0=(0<<ADC7D) | (0<<ADC6D) | (0<<ADC5D) | (0<<ADC4D) | (0<<ADC3D) | (0<<ADC2D) | (0<<ADC1D) | (0<<ADC0D);
ADMUX=ADC_VREF_TYPE;
ADCSRA=(1<<ADEN) | (0<<ADSC) | (1<<ADATE) | (0<<ADIF) | (0<<ADIE) | (1<<ADPS2) | (0<<ADPS1) | (1<<ADPS0);
ADCSRB=(0<<ADTS2) | (0<<ADTS1) | (0<<ADTS0);

// SPI initialization
// SPI disabled
SPCR=(0<<SPIE) | (0<<SPE) | (0<<DORD) | (0<<MSTR) | (0<<CPOL) | (0<<CPHA) | (0<<SPR1) | (0<<SPR0);

// TWI initialization
// TWI disabled
TWCR=(0<<TWEA) | (0<<TWSTA) | (0<<TWSTO) | (0<<TWEN) | (0<<TWIE);

// Alphanumeric LCD initialization
// Connections are specified in the
// Project|Configure|C Compiler|Libraries|Alphanumeric LCD menu:
// RS - PORTC Bit 0
// RD - PORTC Bit 1
// EN - PORTC Bit 2
// D4 - PORTC Bit 4
// D5 - PORTC Bit 5
// D6 - PORTC Bit 6
// D7 - PORTC Bit 7
// Characters/line: 20
lcd_init(20);
     lcd_gotoxy(0,0);
    // display the message
    lcd_putsf("Temp is:");
    lcd_gotoxy(0,1);
    lcd_putsf("? 13 A3 "); 
    //printf("\r\nSwVersion:%d.%d\r\n", SW_VERSION/10, SW_VERSION%10);
while (1)
      {
      // Place your code here

      }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116694/discussion-on-question-by-robinson-chera-only-green-display-but-temperature-its).

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr2fK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr2fK.png) What is this blue component? can you tell me how to get it from proteus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the result. In the while loop I should put the following:

```
while (1)
      {
      // Place your code here
      lcd_clear();
      res=read_adc(0);
      temperature=(res*453)>>10;
      sprintf(buffer, "%f", temperature);
      
      lcd_puts(buffer);
      delay_ms(1500);

      }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At a glance it looks correct, the output of the LM35 (Pin 2: Vout) is connected to Pin 37 (ADC0).

Things I would check:

- Try a voltage probe at pin 37 and make sure the voltage output from LM35 is there (obviously it should, but sanity checks always help).
- Check if configuration is required on port A in the ATmega164 to enable the ADC read function.
- There is no visible earth on the ATmega164, perhaps it is implicit? But it would be absolutely essential for analog read functions.
- Check other required pins for analog function, AREF and AVCC.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the ATmega and its libraries, so I'm just going to give you the things I see on general principles:

1. You call LCD_Cmd and LCD_Out before lcd_init.  That looks to me like you are trying to use the LCD library before you've initialized it.  Some libraries will throw a fit if you do that.
2. ADC_Read will will return a number between 0 and 1023.  You will have to convert that to a voltage between 0 and 5V (that seems to be the reference voltage for the ADC.)  From the voltage, you can calculate the temperature. Refer to the [LM35 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf) for the details of calculating the temperature from the measured voltage.